# Why can't a certain DOM element have CSS styles

Tags: javascript, dom

While developing an Angular app I've come across the following issue: an SVG element didn't have styles from its class (even though it was defined in `<styles>` tag) and what's more peculiar (and the point of the question): **Chrome and Firefox DevTools didn't allow adding element styles manually**.

[image: Chrome DevTools not showing element.styles]
*Note the missing `element.styles` block in the right pane.*

However, if I edit container element HTML and just copy and paste back the markup - it suddenly appears and everything works as expected. So this must happen due to the way the element is added to DOM programmatically. And since this behaviour is identical in both Chrome and Firefox, it is most likely a feature, rather than a bug.

**So how can this be achieved purposedly?**

P.S. For those interested in Angular part, here is a GitHub issue that I reported for this case (also contains a reproduction repo): https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15727

Comment: Did you try clicking the plus sign on the toolbar of the styles pane? That should let you add CSS...

Comment: No, it doesn't. It simply doesn't do anything. And nevertheless, all other elements show `element.styles` block, whereas this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the answer myself. **TL;DR**: element was created with `document.createElementNS` with an unknown namespace (or empty), which made it an `Element`, rather than `SVGElement`. Styles are not defined for base `Elements` according to the specification.

So obviously the key was to check the type of the element - and both Chrome and Firefox have shown that that SVG is created as a base `Element`:

[image: Element is created as a base Element, rather than an HTMLElement or SVGElement]

The next question was how did it happen. TL;DR for this section: due to a bug in Angular's new experimental compiler (probably) it was added with an invalid namespace and the rest is according to specification.

Search through Angular's source revealed the way it creates elements: [createElementNS](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/shared.ts#L188).

Quick experiment with that function has proven the initial guess that the problem was with the element's interface (`Element`), and it can be reproduced by passing an invalid namespace.

And DOM specification revealed exactly why does that happen:

[createElementNS steps](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#internal-createelementns-steps):

> The internal createElementNS steps...:
>   ...
>   4. Return the result of *creating an element* given document, localName, **namespace**, prefix, is, and with the synchronous custom elements flag set.

[Creating an element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-create-element) is defined as follows:

> To create an element, given a document, localName, namespace, and optional prefix, is, and synchronous custom elements flag, run these steps:
>   ...
>   4. Let *definition* be the result of looking up a custom element definition given document, **namespace**, localName, and is.

[Looked up definition](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#look-up-a-custom-element-definition) turns out to be `NULL` in this case:

> To look up a custom element definition, given a document, namespace, localName, and is, perform the following steps. They will return either a custom element definition or null:
>   1. If namespace is not the HTML namespace, **return null**.

Returning to `createElementNS` steps from before:

> ...
>   7. Otherwise: *[definition is null]*
>
> > 1. Let *interface* be the **element interface** for localName and namespace.
> > 2. Set result to a **new element that implements interface**, with no attributes, namespace set to namespace, namespace prefix set to prefix, local name set to localName, custom element state set to "uncustomized", custom element definition set to null, is value set to is, and node document set to document.
> >        ...

And finally, the [*element interface* is defined](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-interface) as follows:

> The element interface for any name and namespace is **Element**, unless stated otherwise.

As for inability to add custom styles, that is due to the missing `style` property on the base `Element`. That's probably due to the [specification of the `style` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-style-attribute):

> All *HTML elements* may have the style content attribute set. This is a style attribute as defined by the CSS Style Attributes specification.

[*HTML elements* are](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#xml):

> To ease migration from HTML to XML, UAs conforming to this specification will place elements in HTML in the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace, at least for the purposes of the DOM and CSS. The term "HTML elements" refers to any element in that namespace, even in XML documents.

However, `style` property exists in `SVGElement`, and probably some other base prototypes, so there must be some other specifications that allow that. But I thought that's out of scope of my original question.

And that concludes my research.